# C# WPF - does a materialdesign pack affect the functions for a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display a selected row from a datagrid into textboxes so I ended up with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=127&v=SDUt4y-H-nw . I followed it step by step but when I test it, it does not work (it does not display the data from the datagrid into the textboxes). This is my code:

```
private void DGBookings_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
            DataRowView row_selected = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            if (row_selected != null)
            {
                textBoxKlant.Text = row_selected["Naam"].ToString();
                dpIncheck.Text = row_selected["Incheckdatum"].ToString();
                dpUitcheck.Text = row_selected["Uitcheckdatum"].ToString();
                dpHotelLocatie.Text = row_selected["Hotel"].ToString();
                dpAantalPersonen.Text = row_selected["Aantal_personen"].ToString();
                dpMedewerker.Text = row_selected["medewerkerid"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

My guess is that it is because I'm using a materialdesign pack... Can this be true? Or is it my code? If it is my code feel free to give suggestions.

Comment: Is your `DataGrid` bound to a data source?

Comment: @dotNET it is like this           `DGBookings.ItemsSource = bookings;`

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would b the case. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DataGrid` is bound to a data source. If that is the case, the following line will cause trouble:

```
DataRowView row_selected = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
```

For bound controls, `SelectedItem` is of the type of underlying collection item and not `DataRowView`. So the above line will set `raw_selected` to `null` and the following block of code will not execute. You should cast it to that type instead and then fill your textboxes directly using the properties of that item.

My suggestion for you is to learn about MVVM. Your VM layer should expose a collection type property for binding `ItemSource` to it, and another property for binding `SelectedItem`. You'll then be able to use this second property to bind your textboxes. There will be no need to use `SelectionChanged` event. In fact, there will be absolutely no user code in Window code-behind file.

### Edit

If you want to stick to event-handling approach, all you need to do is to replace the above line with this:

```
var row_selected = dg.SelectedItem as Booking;
```

I'm assuming that the data type of your items in `bookings` collection is `Booking`. If it is something else, use that type name.

Comment: can you give an example with the code I gave you? Or do you need more? When you can do that I mark your answer ;)

Comment: So it is not possible with `Itemsource`?

Comment: @portalstudent: I do not know anything about the `bookings` collection. What is the type of it? What is the type of its items? If you want to stick to event-handling approach, all you need to change in your code is word `DataRowView` in the above line and replace it with the type of your items.

Comment: By changing it to that line it still does not work :(

Comment: Than I have this error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Booking'` on these lines : `textBoxKlant.Text = row_selected["Naam"]          .ToString();
` > `row_selected["Naam"]`

Comment: Booking is a list.

Comment: If you need morge background information feel free to ask.